# How to do conditional code using lwarp?

Tags: lwarp

I am trying `lwarp` package to compare its performance with tex4ht on large files.

I have small question that I could not find an answer for searching.

I want to use `\begin{dmath*}` environment when compiling with lualatex only, since lwarp with mathjax does not handle the `breqn` package.  But I do not know how to tell it something like the following

```
\iflwarp% is there similar command??
   \begin{align*}.....\end{align*}
\else
   \begin{dmath*}.....\end{dmath*}
\fi
```

Similar to how I do when using tex4ht

```
\ifdefined\HCode
   \begin{align*}.....\end{align*}
\else
   \begin{dmath*}.....\end{dmath*}
\fi
```

Right now, when I compile the `dmath` environment, the math does not display in HTML since mathjax does not know about this environment. It only knows `align` environment.

Here is  MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[mathjax]{lwarp}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
y = \sin x
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
lualatex foo.tex
lualatex foo.tex
lwarpmk html
```

The above ofcourse does not work

[image]

How to handle this? How do I run some Latex code only when using `lualatex` and other code
when using `lwarp`?  I found also some other packages and commands do not work in `lwarp`, so I need to be able to do this type of conditional for other purposes also and not just for the example above.

reference [lwarp package](https://ctan.org/pkg/lwarp?lang=en)

On page 233 of the above document I see `\warpHTMLonly {⟨contents⟩}`

```
 Only process the contents if producing HTML output.
```

But how to do the else part using the above?

**Update**

I found that the following works. But I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[mathjax]{lwarp}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

%use breqn with lualatex only
\ifbool{warpingHTML}{}{\usepackage{breqn}}

\begin{document}

\ifbool{warpingHTML}
{
\begin{align*}
y = \sin x
\end{align*}
}
{
\begin{dmath*}
y = \sin x
\end{dmath*}
}
\end{document}
```

And now compiling using

```
lualatex foo.tex
lualatex foo.tex
lwarpmk html
```

gives the web page

[image]

So it worked. Is this the recommend way then to do conditional in lwarp?

Comment: `\warpprintonly`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[mathjax]{lwarp}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{warpprint}
\usepackage{breqn}
\end{warpprint}

\begin{document}

\begin{warpHTML}
  \begin{align*}
    y = \sin x
  \end{align*}
\end{warpHTML}
\begin{warpprint}
  \begin{dmath*}
    y = \sin x
  \end{dmath*}
\end{warpprint}

\end{document}
```

This is documented in section 7.10 of the manual.

There is also a `warpMathJax` environment for alternatives to constructs that do not play well with MathJax but are OK for SVG mathematics.